# Possible features for MDM in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution for android device. I have found out few feature that are possible for this application:

1. Remote lock
2. Wipe data
3. Password policy
4. Disable Camera
5. Manage Applications

I have done all the things mentioned above. Is there any other possible feature that I can include in my application ? some feature using native android programming ?

Comment: asking about what are the things are possible in android programming?

Comment: Can you brief me on how managing the application can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are alot of things to do in the arena of MDM policy and its implmentations like for example:

- Backup/Restore.
- New apps Installation notifications.
- GPS tracking and mapping.

and for more information about those implmentation you can start by reading the following [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management)

Comment: Could you please explain me about Backup/Restore in MDM, android?

Comment: for backup like backing up the contacts, Photos from the device before wipe it, and for restore you have to make your app capable to retrieve its data that already saved in it before wiping the device or re-installing the app. Since you already consider the possibility of wiping remote device by the policy you defined above. Here is a sample code for backup and restoring app by android developer website to give you clear start    http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/src/com/example/android/backuprestore/BackupRestoreActivity.html

Comment: Thanks, any idea about uninstall app in android in silent mode?

Comment: Here is a good example to start with how you can monitor the app installation and un-installation http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98 ,

Answer (score 0):

Some I can think right off the bat are:

1. Monitoring : Administrator can monitor device status .A lot of info available here, like battery, location, uptime, network usage history etc.
2. Settings : Administrator can configure the device.